# How to find out user's language in an EJB3 SessionBean?

Tags: internationalization, ejb-3.0

we have an JSF2.0 / EJB3.0 Application. Is it possible to access user's language/locale from within a StatelessSessionBean? For example something like that?

```
@Stateless
@Local(MyService.class)
public class MyServiceBean implements MyService {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext context;

    public void doSomething() {
        Principal principal = context.getCallerPrincipal();

        // how to get acccess to user's language ?
        Locale locale = ...
    }
}
```

Of course it is possible to pass the Locale from web tier to ejb tier by parameter to each method. But is this the smartest variant?

Is there a better solution similar to **context.getCallerPrincipal();**

I am looking for somthing like: **context.getCallerLocale();**

Thanks for your help.
Viktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such standard feature.  One technique is to use a thread-local, but you need to carefully ensure you call .remove() to avoid causing problems with your container's thread pool.  The only other alternative is to use a vendor-specific feature, such as WebSphere Application Server's [Internationalization service](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/i18n/concepts/cin_intserv.html).